# Cannot get multiprocessing to work

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, jupyter-notebook

I have to implement a parallel piece of software for computing a large scale distance matrix.

This is the code I wrote:

```
subset = #[list of proper objects]
nthreads = 10

def compute_distance_corcoeff(geneset, offset, q):
    for i in range(offset, len(geneset), nthreads):
        g1 = geneset[i]
        dvect = [np.corrcoef(g1.expr, g2.expr)[0,1] for g2 in geneset]
        q.put((i,dvect))

queue = Queue()
processes = []
for off in range(nthreads):
    processes.append(Process(target=compute_distance_corcoeff, args=(subset, off, queue)))

for p in processes:
    p.start()
for p in processes:
    p.join()
```

I will then collect partial results from the Queue.

Unfortunately, it looks like nothing is happening. It seems it get stuck at the `join()`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: what do you mean by "proper objects"? if you put print statements in the `compute_distance_corcoeff` to check that it is actually running does it get printed? Maybe it is just taking really long, how big is `subset`?

Comment: I suggest you use a [`multiprocessing.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) and then `join()` the `Pool` object created. If you're using Windows, be sure to use add an `if __name__ == '__main__:` to separate the main process' code from that of the subprocesses.

Comment: perhaps a `p.close()` is missing?

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the [multiprocessing programming guidelines](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#programming-guidelines), you must first empty the `Queue` and then you can join the `Process`.

Your logic ends up in a deadlock as the processes cannot terminate because they are waiting for the messages in the `Queue` to be consumed.